# Coloring Eyebrows in Lightroom CC without Photoshop

Tags: lightroom, portrait, color, color-correction

I use Lightroom CC (not classic), and my model has requested to change the color of her eyebrows to match her hair colors.

No problem, I thought, I could just mask out the blacks in her eyebrows using a combination of Brush + Color Selection, then use the "Colorize" option to colour them pink.

[image]
[image]

However, I could not finely select the eyebrows (it seemed to target the skin underneath the eyebrows instead). In addition, the colorized color appears to be too saturated unlike the slightly desaturated pink in her hair, dialling the saturation slider back did not have much effect.

[image: my attempt]

Is it possible to color the eyebrows preferably only using Lightroom CC? I can  use Photoshop as a last resort.

[Link to DNG](https://sutdapac-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/chester_koh_mymail_sutd_edu_sg/EYydeFYOichDsNfdNMgWZVsBFlWMqf2cnEiYUVWdGo8cQw?e=VAR5PQ)

Comment: Do you have an actual requirement to do this in Lightroom, or could you do it in GIMP or some other free editing tool?

Comment: i suppose i can do it in GIMP or even Photoshop if it is easier. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot effectively colorize black or white as it retains the luminance value. What you want is not easily achievable. IMO you would be better off removing the eyebrows and repainting them with a custom hair brush. And doing it convincingly won't be that easy. LR is not up to the task...